# How to allow specific CORS origins, headers, and methods for OWIN token requests?

Tags: cors, owin, asp.net-web-api2

We are using web api and OWIN to create our own authentication and authorization providers. It all works great, but now we are tasked with allowing CORS requests.

`CorsHttpConfigurationExtensions` work for our api, and we've also got the token request handled using `CorsExtensions`. Here's the thing, though: this line

```
 app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

in `Startup.ConfigureAuth()` allows all origins, header items, and methods, does it not? It's the equivalent of

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

in `WebApiConfig.Configure()` - right? There is only the one enum value `AllowAll` for `CorsOptions`. And there is no place to decorate the token route with any kind of attribute.

I'm not so concerned about the headers and the verbs (methods); presumably the OWIN assembly is handling those, restricting to POST, for instance. But we would really like to restrict origin headers to specific  domains. Does anyone know how we could make this happen?

Answer (score 5):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using System.Web.Cors;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRSelfHost.Startup))]

namespace SignalRSelfHost
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var policy = new CorsPolicy()
            {
                AllowAnyHeader = true,
                AllowAnyMethod = true,
                SupportsCredentials = true
            };

            // list of domains that are allowed can be added here
            policy.Origins.Add("domain"); 
            //be sure to include the port:
            //example: "http://localhost:8081"

            app.UseCors(new CorsOptions
            {
                PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
                {
                    PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(policy)
                }
            });

            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001735/specify-domain-in-owin-startup-class)

Answer (score 0):

With OWIN OAuth when you grant the token, you should add the origin header to the response, and there you can add the origin that you want, have a look to this tutorial, it gets the origin associated with the client and that what get injected into the header as the origin.

http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/

Hope that helps.