# Specify Domain in Owin Startup Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, signalr, cors, owin

I've created a self hosting Owin/SignalR app with code similar to the code in this tutorial:

[SignalR Self Host Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host)

Everything works, but for security-sake, I'd like to limit it to only allow messages from a specific remote site.  In other words, I'd like to replace the "app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);" line with code to confine the app to only responding to messages from a URL that I define, i.e. only allow messages from, say, http://www.remote_site.com or something.  Is there any easy way to do this?

For reference, here is the code for my SignalR startup class:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;

namespace SignalRSelfHost
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();

        // How do I only allow a specific URL instead of the "CorsOptions.AllowAll" option?             
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is the full implementation of the `Owin Startup` class:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using System.Web.Cors;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRSelfHost.Startup))]

namespace SignalRSelfHost
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var policy = new CorsPolicy()
            {
                AllowAnyHeader = true,
                AllowAnyMethod = true,
                SupportsCredentials = true
            };

            policy.Origins.Add("domain"); //be sure to include the port:
//example: "http://localhost:8081"

            app.UseCors(new CorsOptions
            {
                PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
                {
                    PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(policy)
                }
            });

            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to server to accept a list  of domains, you simply add them to the `Origins`.

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: That looks great!  I found a solution that set the CorsOptions with a Lazy<T> and a bunch of lambdas that worked, but it wasn't as simple as this.  +1!!!

Comment: I initially saw this method used by one of the guys who wrote SignalR, so I would go with this one:))

But if you think yours solves the issue just as well, you should post it (just in case someone else needs it) and mark one of them as answer.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 7):

Here's the code that I mentioned in a comment above:

```
public class Startup
{

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(_corsOptions.Value);
        app.MapSignalR(); 
    }


    private static Lazy<CorsOptions> _corsOptions = new Lazy<CorsOptions>(() =>
    {
        return new CorsOptions
        {
            PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
            {
                PolicyResolver = context =>
                {
                    var policy = new CorsPolicy();
                    policy.Origins.Add("http://localhost:8081");
                    policy.AllowAnyMethod = true;
                    policy.AllowAnyHeader = true;
                    policy.SupportsCredentials = true;
                    return Task.FromResult(policy);
                }
            }
        };
    });

}
```

This works, but I think Matei's answer above is cleaner and simpler.