# Owin - Hosting multiple websites with different hostname using the same port

Tags: c#, owin

It is possible to configure OWIN for listening on specific domain name?

Currently I have setup OWIN for listening on port 80

```
WebApp.Start<StartOwin>("http://*:80");
```

But I want something like this:

```
WebApp.Start<StartOwin>("http://myWebSite.com:80");
```

I want do this because I have a few websites which are hosted on the same machine, and they uses the same port (:80), these websites are hosted on IIS.

Maybe it is possible with CORS? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32005134/7131875

Comment: Yes. As long as the host name is different, the host will bind to the correct address.